# How to distinguish Nexus 7 (2012) and Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: nexus-7

I am having trouble with Bluetooth Low Energy (BT 4.0) on a Nexus 7.  I think I may have a 2012 model.

How to tell if I have a 2012 or 2013 version of the Nexus 7?

Comment: Look at the back. If you can read "Nexus" while the tablet is in a portrait orientation, it's the 2012 model. If it's sideways, it's the 2013.

Comment: @Krampus That's a really good, concise answer. If you were to post it as an answer, I for one would upvote it.

Comment: It does have the virtue of not requiring the unit to be powered on. But dotVezz's answer has images which show this anyway.

Comment: BTW the 2012 model is NOT BT 4.0 (BLE, Smart Ready, etc...) compatible, even though it can be upgraded to android 4.3.  The 2013 model is BT 4.0 compatible.

Comment: Just see if the tablet has a rear camera!!  if it has its 2013 model. ENOUGH SAID

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are several physical differences

- Most notable is the different orientations of the "Nexus" logo.
- The 2013 model drops the dimpled texture on the back.
- The 2013 model also has a camera on the back, which the 2012 model lacks.
- The 2013 model has a notification LED on the front, which the 2012 model lacks.
- The 2013 model has a speaker grille on the top for stereo sound in landscape, while the 2012 model only has the bottom speaker grille.

2013:

[image: The 2013 Model has a large, vertically-aligned logo.]

2012:

[image: The 2012 model has a small, horizontally-aligned logo.]

Comment: Looking at those images the 2013 model also has a front camera and a notification led, both of which the 2012 model lack.

Comment: With android 4.3 my build number on a 2013 model is JWR66N.  Maybe the "razor" refers to a different android version?

Comment: @monzie Thanks. I must have been confused - I have now removed that part of the answer.

Comment: @bmdixon — Don't you mean a back camera?

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that after posting but couldn't edit it. It's right in the answer though :)

Comment: @monzie "razor" is the board/device codename; it's unfortunately not displayed on that screen. But you can see it at https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images for example. I don't think it displays anywhere in the stock About screen

Comment: @derobert, he was referring to an incorrect statement that was in my answer. I've removed it since.

Comment: @dotVezz I know, I looked at the edit history... Its only half-wrong; they do indeed refer to the 2012 and 2013 models... They just aren't displayed. It'd be even better if they just clarified the model number on the screen, to "Nexus 7 (2012)" and "Nexus 7 (2013)". [I assume they don't; I only have a Nexus 5 and Nexus 10 in front of me to check.]